# Listview not visibly being populated

Tags: android, user-interface, listview

I have a method which reads data from a csv file and then creates an object containing this data. The data is then used to inflate a custom row view with a custom adapter to populate a list view. The first row should be displayed and then a short delay before adding the next row to the list.

The problem is that when the method is called the screen goes black for the total delay time (if delay time is 1 second with 5 messages = 5 seconds of blackness) then the ListView is displayed with all the rows, instead of showing it being populated one at a time.

playChat Method:

```
public void playChat(){
    View row = null;
    int delay = 1000;

    try{
        InputStream is = this.getAssets().open("chat.csv");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;

        while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
            String[] rowData = line.split(",");
            ChatText current = new ChatText();

            current.setUser(rowData[0]);
            current.setChatText(rowData[1]);

            chatTexts.add(current);

            playView.invalidateViews();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My Custom Adapter:

```
public ChatAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ChatText> chatTexts){
    super(context, R.layout.chat_layout_left,chatTexts);
    this.ctx = context;
}

public View getView(final int pos, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;

    String user = getItem(pos).getUser();

    if (null == row){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)ctx).getLayoutInflater();

        holder = new DetailHolder();
        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);

        holder.txtUser = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtUser);

        holder.txtChatText = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtChatText);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (DetailHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_one);
    holder.txtUser.setText(getItem(pos).getUser());
    holder.txtChatText.setText(getItem(pos).getChatText());

    return row;
}
```

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that it looks like you might be doing this on the main thread, which means with sleep() you're going to lock the entire UI until the loop is done.

You'll want something like this (my syntax might be slightly off, but it should be close):

```
public synchronized void playChat(){
    InputStream is = this.getAssets().open("chat.csv");
    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        View row = null;
        int delay = 1000;
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            try{
                String line;
                while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
                    String[] rowData = line.split(",");
                    ChatText current = new ChatText();

                    current.setUser(rowData[0]);
                    current.setChatText(rowData[1]);

                    addChatText(current);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(delay);
                    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private synchronized void addChatText(final ChatText current){
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    chatTexts.add(current);
                    playView.invalidateViews();
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Also, don't forget to close everything after :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you should never put "blocking code" in the main thread. For instance, the code `Thread.sleep(delay)` will stop the main thread for that amount of time. The main thread is where Android updates the UI. That is why your screen goes black.

You can read more about this here: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

A way of achieving what you want to do is by the use of the AssyncTask class. Here is how I think your code could be:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class UpdateListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ListView mListView;

    public UpdateListTask(ListView listView) {
        mListView = listView;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        mListView.invalidateViews();
    }
}
```